# Empty hash and 'Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=)'

Tags: perl, nagios

i've got a question about this code i found on [github](https://github.com/jasonhancock/nagios-puppet/blob/master/plugins/check_pupdash_nodes"github") and changed to my needs. It's generally working fine but i get some warnings that worry me.

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at ./check_puppetdash line 192.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at ./check_puppetdash line 192.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at ./check_puppetdash line 192.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at ./check_puppetdash line 192.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at ./check_puppetdash line 192.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at ./check_puppetdash line 192.
```

Line 192 looks like this:

```
189 # Gather values for status details
190 my $details = '';
191 foreach (@interests) {
192    if ($nodes{$_} >= $thresholds_warning{$_}){          
193        $details = $details . $_ . " = " . $nodes{$_} . "; ";
194  }
195 }
```

I pinned it down to the hash %nodes that gets defined above:

```
# Parse the markup, loading up anything that matches into the %nodes hash
my %nodes;
foreach my $line(split('\n', $response->decoded_content)) {
if($line=~m/<a href="\/nodes\/(\w+)">(\d+)<\/a>/) {
    $nodes{$1} = $2;
 }
}

#Gather perfomance data
foreach my $interest(@interests) {
$np->add_perfdata(
    label => $interest,
    value => defined($nodes{$interest}) ? $nodes{$interest} : 0,
    uom   => undef,
 );
}
```

I used that part from the existing script.
When i print the content of %nodes anywhere in the script i get an empty line.

I'm not very experienced in perl and would appreciate some tips.

PS: I also contacted the developer of the original code.

Comment: Likely the regex matching on HTML `a` tags isn't working. Add `print "$line\n";` to the %nodes code to see what the content is. Could be any number of things (uppercase `A`, whitespace somewhere in the tag, etc). This is why it's generally not recommended to parse HTML/XML with regex.

Comment: Alternatively, look at the source HTML you're parsing. It would also help to provide a sample here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer, because the root of it is this line:

```
if($line=~m/<a href="\/nodes\/(\w+)">(\d+)<\/a>/) {
```

The empty `%nodes` implies that isn't matching. At a guess, that's because the URL Format has changed slightly - or maybe there's been a line feed inserted into the link or ... well, anything really.

It *will* match:

```
<a href="/nodes/node1">10</a>
```

And you'll get a hash element:

```
 node1 => 10
```

But it *won't* match:

```
<a href="/root/nodes/node1">10</a>
<a href="/nodes/node-1">10</a>
<a href="nodes/node1">10</a>
<a href="/nodes/node1">10 </a>
<a href="/nodes/node1">
   10
</a>

<a href="/nodes/node1">node1</a>
<A HREF="/nodes/node1">10</A>
```

Etc.

This is one of the reasons why regex based parsing of HTML is a bad idea. Fixing this will require consulting the source HTML and finding a new regex which will match - but with no URL or sample HTML we can't help.

I would suggest what you need is to insert:

```
print $response->decoded_content
```

And see what you get in your `a href`s.

Comment: Thanks, i found the error when i used "print $response->decoded_content". It got directed to the wrong url, because wrong parameters where used in the execution of the script. The script itself is fine.

Comment: @chr126, I'd not consider it 'fine' until it throw a more useful error when given wrong parameters.  Imagine how the next guy will fell.